# sails model query findOne to search by id from assosiation

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

how to  query findOne to search by id from assosiation on sails?

my example model :

```
1. model Stream.js

    module.exports = {
         attributes: {
           title: { type: "string" },
           author: { model: "media_account" } 
         },
         schema: true
       };

 2. model Media_account.js

    module.exports = {
      attributes: {
        name: { type: "string" },
        streams: {
          collection: 'stream',
          via: 'author'
        }
       },
       schema: true

      };
```

how to get all streams best author?
i'm try bellow query but always return empty array

```
Stream.find({author: "12345"});
```

on my db stream with author "12345" is exit's if i check via mongo console

```
db.stream.find({author: Objectid("12345")});   

result :

[{
  id: "1ddd2323ef",
  title: "haha",
  author: "12345"
}]
```

Comment: Hello
did you find any solution for this?